# Understanding pointers in a structure and malloc

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I am just learning C (reading Sam's Teach Yourself C in 24 hours). I've gotten through pointers and memory allocation, but now I'm wondering about them inside a structure.

I wrote the little program below to play around, but I'm not sure if it is OK or not. Compiled on a Linux system with gcc with the `-Wall` flag compiled with nothing amiss, but I'm not sure that is 100% trustworthy.

Is it ok to change the allocation size of a pointer as I have done below or am I possibly stepping on adjacent memory? I did a little before/after variable in the structure to try to check this, but don't know if that works and if structure elements are stored contiguously in memory (I'm guessing so since a pointer to a structure can be passed to a function and the structure manipulated via the pointer location). Also, how can I access the contents of the pointer location and iterate through it so I can make sure nothing got overwritten if it is contiguous? I guess one thing I'm asking is how can I debug messing with memory this way to know it isn't breaking anything?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct hello {
    char *before;
    char *message;
    char *after;
};

int main (){
    struct hello there= {
        "Before",
        "Hello",
        "After",
    };
    printf("%ld\n", strlen(there.message));
    printf("%s\n", there.message);
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(there));
    there.message = malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
    there.message = "Hello, there!";
    printf("%ld\n", strlen(there.message));
    printf("%s\n", there.message);
    printf("%s %s\n", there.before, there.after);
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(there));
    return 0;
}
```

I'm thinking something is not right because the size of my `there` didn't change.kj

Kind regards,

Comment: "Teach Yourself C in 24 hours"... oh my. There's a list of books in the [C tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info). Do yourself a favor and stay away from anything that advertises teaching you C in X days/hours/minutes.

Comment: if i could only learn to launch a rocket in 24 hrs !!

Comment: @narnie please savour the moment that you learn C no need to hurry. its really a memory to cherish even if apocalypse is tomorrow evening.

Comment: @BarathBushan This is the second C book I have started. The first was C from Novice to Professional, but got bogged down with pointers. Sam's book helped clear that up, then I'll be going back to the Apress book. Thanks for the C tag wiki link!

Comment: I'm trying to decide :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really ok, you have a memory leak, you could use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to detect it at runtime (on Linux).

You are coding:

```
there.message = malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
there.message = "Hello, there!";
```

The first assignment call [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html). First, when calling `malloc` you should always test if it fails. But indeed it usually succeeds. So better code at least:

```
there.message = malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
if (!there.message) 
  { perror("malloc of 20 failed"); exit (EXIT_FAILURE); }
```

The second assignment put the address of the constant literal string `"Hello, there!"` into the same pointer `there.message`, and you have lost the first value. You probably want to copy that constant string

```
strncpy (there.message, "Hello, there!", 20*sizeof(char));
```

(you could use just [strcpy(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html) but beware of buffer overflows)

You could get a fresh copy (in heap) of some string using [strdup(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) (and GNU libc has also [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) ...)

```
there.message = strdup("Hello, There");
if (!there.message) 
  { perror("strdup failed"); exit (EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

At last, it is good taste to `free` at program end the heap memory.
(But the operating system would supress the process space at [_exit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/_exit.2.html) time.

Read more about *C programming*, [memory management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management), [garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29). Perhaps consider using [Boehm's conservative GC](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/)

A C pointer is just a memory address zone. Applications need to know their size.

<sup>PS. manual memory management in C is tricky, even for seasoned veteran programmers.</sup>

Comment: Oh wow, you also just answered another question I have had. I've been having the dickens of a time finding the documentation for functions. Didn't know it was on the man 3 pages. Is there somewhere where the entire libraries document each function? Such as, what are all the functions available in the math library?

Comment: `man` pages are old fashion on Linux and Unix systems. Just type `man man` on a Linux terminal to find out.

Comment: I love man pages. I have actually written my own man pages with the syntax they uses for programs I have written before. Any advise on how to find the documentation for all the libraries? I was hoping to find it in the gcc docs, but library descriptions weren't there.

Comment: The `intro` *man* page of some section could help. Most free software libraries have their documentation. For GNU libc, start [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/documentation.html)

Comment: OK, that GNU libc link is perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: So, in looking at the man page for strncpy, if with my initial defining of `there.message` being only of length 6*sizeof(char) (The `hello` + `\0`), it seems the memory allocation for there.message is only that size. If I use strncpy, which copies to the memory location of there.message and that memory location has only been allocated that smaller size, isn't putting a string that is `20*sizeof(char)` overflowing the buffer? the `size_t n` argument to strncpy doesn't increase the allocation it seems to me, but limits the number of characters that goes into the buffer. No?

Answer (score 0):

`there.message = "Hello, there!"` does not copy the string into the buffer.  It sets the pointer to a new (generally static) buffer holding the string "Hello, there!".  Thus, the code as written has a memory leak (allocated memory that never gets freed until the program exits).

But, yes, the malloc is fine in its own right.  You'd generally use a strncpy, sprintf, or similar function to copy content into the buffer thus allocated.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it ok to change the allocation size of a pointer [...] ?

Huh? What do you mean by "changing the allocation size of a pointer"? Currently all your code does is leaking the 20 bytes you `malloc()`ated by assigning a different address to the pointer.

Comment: I may not have the proper terminology, but what I'm meaning is that the `*message` pointer when I initialize `there` is 5+1 char's long ("Hello" plus the \0). If I need to change it to a longer string as I have done (changing it to "Hello, there"), how can I do that?

Comment: @narnie `there.message = "Hello there";` since you are working with string literals.

Comment: Ah, so I don't have to extend the memory if adding to the length of a shorter pointer to a string? It won't step on other memory? The compiler with handle it?

Comment: @narnie See, string literals are constant strings with static storage duration, they exist throughout the lifetime of the program, **and** you're only *assigning the pointer itself.* You don't do `memcpy()`. If you called `memcpy()` or `strcpy()`, then you would have had to allocate memory for it, but this way you don't.

Comment: OK, it is starting to congeal a bit. I didn't understand that about string literals before now. Seems rather wasteful. I guess there is no way to free that back up?

Comment: @narnie No, that's what "memory leak" means.