# C programming , need help understanding some concept

Tags: c, terminology

This is a very simple program I have done in C and works fine but I don't understand some terminology:

Instead of `list[list_size] = strdup(file)` I do:

1. `char*test=file` and `strcpy(list[list_size],test)`. I get
   segmentation fault.
2. `char*test=malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_FILENAME_LEN+1)` and `test=file`
   and`strcpy(list[list_size],test)`. I get segmentation fault.
3. Or even `strcpy(list[list_size],file)`. I get segmentation fault.

   ```
     # include < stdio.h > 
     # include < string.h > 
     # define MAX_LIST_SIZE 1000
     # define MAX_FILENAME_LEN 128

     int main() {
     FILE * infile;
     char * list[MAX_LIST_SIZE],
     file[MAX_FILENAME_LEN + 1];
     size_t list_size = 0;
     infile = popen("ls", "r");

     if (infile != NULL) {

         while ((list_size < MAX_LIST_SIZE) &&(fscanf(infile, "%s", file) == 1)) {

             list[list_size] = strdup(file);

             list_size++;

             puts(file);
         }
     }
     pclose(infile);
     return 0;
   ```

   }

It would be great if someone could help.

Comment: Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16535800/841108) to a very similar question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The non-standard strdup function does two things: it allocates dynamic memory and it copies the string. It is the very same thing as calling malloc followed by a call to strcpy (which is why strdup is a 100% superfluous function).

   When you do `strcpy(list[list_size],test)`, list isn't pointing at any allocated memory - it is pointing at a random memory location anywhere in the memory. You try to copy data into this random location and get a crash.
2. You allocate memory and point at it with `test`. Then you forget all about that memory when you let `test` point at `file` instead, you have created a memory leak. And once you have done that, you do the very same bug as in 1, since the variables `test` and `file` have nothing to do with `list`.
3. Same bug as in 1 and 2.

I would advise studying pointers and arrays a bit more before diving into dynamic memory allocation and string handling.

Comment: Thanks man, great answer ; so array of characters are actually pointers ... Thanks , just learned something new.

Comment: @user2341716 No! An array of characters is an array of characters. (If you use the array name without [], you will get a pointer to the first element.) This however: `char * list[MAX_LIST_SIZE]` is an _array of pointers to characters_.

Answer (score 2):

```
char *list[MAX_LIST_SIZE];
```

Here, the elements of `list` are uninitialized, they don't point to valid memory, hence your program invokes undefined behavior. `strcpy()` returns a pointer that's either `NULL` or points to some `malloc()`ated memory, which is, consequentially, valid.